# Excluding a specific folder's content from deletion

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, script, shell-script

So I have a one-liner for deleting content from multiple folders, but there is 1 folder whos contents I do not want to delete. So if I had folders A, B, C, D, and E, I want to delete all files from these folder EXCEPT folder C. I've tried the "-exclude" function and "? {$folder -ne "C"}" and a few others but nothing is working. I'm sure this is super simple, but could someone please help me with this. My current one-liner is:

```
Remove-Item \\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\ProcessorHandlers\C\*.* -Recurse -Force
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since -exclude should work, you may have to be more specific about what you tried. Adding a simple -exclude "C" should work.

Comment: @Silbee I've tried doing -Exclude *C* and "C" and neither worked. I've tried another one liner that someone from another post revised, which was:

Remove-Item \\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\ProcessorHandlers\Test\*.* -Recurse -Force

And that's really about it. Haven't done too much else, as I thought the -Exclude function should work.

Comment: @Silbee That first one I said for -Exclude, that is the letter C contained by two * symbols. I forgot it would Italicize it on here

Comment: There's an answer already formulated on stackoverflow here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-subfolder This also explains why a simple -exclude doesnt work.

Comment: @Silbee I've been to that thread before but I didn't scroll down as far as I did this time, but I indeed found a solution that works like a charm while also teaching me some new stuff. Thanks!

Comment: And thus the answer may be `Get-ChildItem -Exclude C | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` per the already formulated answer on SO per your explanation for an example.

Comment: @Zero596 Maybe you could create an answer to this thread with the correct solution and relevant information ? That way if people possible get directed here, they can find the solution more easely.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to find an answer through the link that @Silbee posted in the comments above. After quite some time trying to get the -Exclude function to work, it just wouldn't. It seems as though -Exclude works on files rather than folders but I could be completely wrong. This code below is what helped me instantly.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PowerShell\Test -Recurse | ? {($_.FullName -notlike "*C*")} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

The deletion process skipped over the C folder and its contents and continued on with the other folder contents (A, B, D, and E).

The "?" is acting as an alias to the Where-Object cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling to get Remove-Item work filtering/excluding a folder.
[This](https://gayanstechblog.wordpress.com/2019/12/03/powershell-delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-sub-folder/) worked for me.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TestFolder -Exclude SubFolder1,SubFolder2 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

**P.S.**: Powershell examples are **[so poorly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3)**. I mean there is not a single example for `-Filter`, for instance.